# I need to make animation appear randomly on same type of div but different ILs, everytime I hit a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

The animation has to appear randomly on my letters, using only **1 checkbox** or it can appear from 1st to the last one but with the delay, if you can do both please show me <3. Probably JS needed. (I'm new to code). I only managed to make it appear as single stroke with 1 checkbox and the animation applied to all letters, but it's not what I want because the color is the same on every letter.

HTML

```
<div class="word">
    <ul>
      <li style="position: relative;">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div class=beautiful>H</div>
      </li>
      <li >
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div class=beautiful>E</div>
      </li >
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div class=beautiful>L</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div class=beautiful>L</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div class=beautiful>O</div>
      </li>
      
      <li class="apellido"">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div class=beautiful>W</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div class=beautiful>O</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div class=beautiful>R</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div class=beautiful>L</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <div class=beautiful>D</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  label {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: -330px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div {
    color: yellow;
    text-shadow: 0 0 15px yellow, 0 0 25px yellow;
    animation: glow 2s linear infinite;
  }

.beautiful {
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:50px;
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow: 5px 1px 9px rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
    color: #1b1e24;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  @keyframes glow {
    0% {
      filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  .body {
      display: flex;
  }

  .word {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 33px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I made the assumption that you only had 1 checkbox per letter based on your attempts and that this wasn't a requirement.*

My example uses 3 different methods of activating your animation: **All at once, in order (*one-by-one*), and random (*one-by-one*)**.

Using `querySelectorAll` in JavaScript, you can get all of the elements containing letters (as they all have the `beautiful` class). From here, you can either immiately enable the animation by adding a class, or loop through each element/letter and add the class for a one-by-one effect.

```js
// All at once
document.querySelector("#allAtOnce").addEventListener("click", e => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".beautiful").forEach(l => l.classList.toggle("colors", e.target.checked))
})

// In order
document.querySelector("#inOrder").addEventListener("click", e => {
  _LightUp(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".beautiful")), e.target);
})

// random
document.querySelector("#random").addEventListener("click", e => {
  _LightUp(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".beautiful")).sort((a, b) => Math.random()-.5), e.target);
})

const _LightUp = (letters, checkbox) => {
  letters[0].classList.toggle("colors", checkbox.checked)
  letters.splice(0, 1);
  if(letters.length) setTimeout(_LightUp, 100, letters, checkbox);
}
```

```css
ul {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  label {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.beautiful {
  font-family:'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:50px;
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-style:italic;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-shadow: 5px 1px 9px rgb(0, 0, 0); 
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
  color: #1b1e24;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.colors {
  color: yellow;
  text-shadow: 0 0 15px yellow, 0 0 25px yellow;
  animation: glow 2s linear infinite;
}

  @keyframes glow {
    0% {
      filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
  
  .body {
      display: flex;
  }

  .word {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 33px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="word">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class=beautiful>H</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=beautiful>E</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=beautiful>L</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=beautiful>L</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=beautiful>O</div>
    </li>

    <li style="margin: 0 0 0 1em;">
      <div class=beautiful>W</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=beautiful>O</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=beautiful>R</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=beautiful>L</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class=beautiful>D</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<input id="allAtOnce" type="checkbox" /> All At Once
<br>
<input id="inOrder" type="checkbox" /> In Order
<br>
<input id="random" type="checkbox" /> Random
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a good explanation <3